# PHP: execute a function which appends a variable with results from a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

dev: wordpress

I got this code online, and it works great for excluding one category ID from a list... but when I try to exclude multiple categories, its only picking up the first one

```
function list_role_term_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
    $tax_type1 = 'category'; //string (word variable)
    $cat_array = array(106, 108); //array (set) of integers (number variables)
    foreach( $cat_array as $cat_id_value )
    {   
        $children_of_parent_cat = implode(',',get_term_children($cat_id_value,$tax_type1)); // get all child categories
        $children_of_parent_cat = (empty($children_of_parent_cat) ? '' : ",$children_of_parent_cat"); // if childs empty or not
        return $exclusions . " AND (t.term_id NOT IN ($cat_id_value ".$children_of_parent_cat." ))"; // Exclude parent and all child cats
    }
    unset($cat_id_value);

}
```

so with this function it will successfully exclude ID 106 from categories... but not 108 (the 2nd in the array), but my goal is I want $exclusions to contain both 106 and 108 so that they can be excluded

bonus points if theres a way to assign a variable at the top like
category ID = 11,12,13
tag ID = 34,25,66

so that it can exclude specific category IDs and taxonomy IDs

Comment: Change `return $exclusions . "...";` to `$exclusions .= "...";` and put `return $exclusions;` _after_ the foreach instead. If you put the return inside the foreach, then it will stop the loop at that point (in the first iteration).

Comment: wow, you are super fast and exactly correct lol. Thank you for the explanation aswell! how do I assign your comment as the correct answer? alsowhats the difference between . and .= after a variable? and how do I give your profile a +1

Comment: I posted an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `return` inside the `foreach`, it will abort the rest of the loop, which means that you will only get the value from the first iteration.

Change your code to:

```php
foreach( $cat_array as $cat_id_value )
{   
    $children_of_parent_cat = implode(',',get_term_children($cat_id_value,$tax_type1)); // get all child categories
    $children_of_parent_cat = (empty($children_of_parent_cat) ? '' : ",$children_of_parent_cat"); // if childs empty or not
    // Remove the return and only append the string
    $exclusions .= " AND (t.term_id NOT IN ($cat_id_value ".$children_of_parent_cat." ))"; // Exclude parent and all child cats
}

return $exclusions;
```

Now it won't return the string until the loop is finished.

Comment: thanks! quick question, if you put = after a variable does that "set" while .= after a variable "appends"?

Comment: @dmstr00 - Yes. `$foo = 'hello';` will set the value (and replace any existing value), while `$foo .= 'hello';` will append the value at the end (short for: `$foo = $foo . 'hello';`)